# Who is the author of the scripture named Maya Samhita?

Tags: scripture, name, shilpa-shastras

Wikipedia contains the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Samhita) information about Maya Samhita

> Maya Samhita (Sanskrit:मय संहिता,Mayasaṁhitā) is a treatise on Hindu
>   Shilpa Shastras. A **certain Maya** is said to have written this book
>   along with Hora Shastra.

What does it mean by certain Maya? Is there any other name for the author?

Comment: by name it seems Maya Dānava...